# How can I merge these 3,500 mixed-charset text files?

Tags: linux, text

I have about 3,500 text files, of mixed character sets: ISO-8859, UTF-8, ASCII, UTF-16, and maybe others.

I want to merge them all into one unicode text file, so I can run a Python script on it that expects it.

If I use `cat`, it doesn't exactly work.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you know which files have which encodings?  Does each file have only a single encoding?

Comment: @phs a file can have more than 1 encoding??  Oh my mind @_@

Comment: A well-formed one won't but as you saw with `cat`, it is easy to make a file that mixes them.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them up-front with a tool like `iconv`, or load them into Python with the correct encoding (by [setting the correct encoding to `open`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)).

If you don't know what the encoding of each file is, then it is more complicated, because you'll need to detect the encoding of each file. There are many heuristics, but not absolutely standard way to do this. Again, using `iconv` can help a lot here.

Comment: I'm currently trying `iconv` now.  I can tell the encoding using file if I want to.  I'm trying `iconv -c -t UTF-8 * > everything.txt`

Comment: I imagine `iconv -c -t UTF-8` on a UTF-16 text will lead to a disastrous result...

Comment: So you have to add either `-f UTF-16`, `-f UTF-8` or `-f ISO-8859-1`.  I hope you really don't need to guess the input encoding.